# How to get elements of lis inside an ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, loops, each

Hi guys I'm trying to get the ids of the `<li>` but im getting undefined, I'm using laravel.

This is in my view

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="listas">
                        @foreach(Auth::user()->empresas as $empresa)
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="seleccion" id="{{$empresa->id}}" data-id="{{$empresa->id}}"
                                   data-nombre="{{$empresa->nombre}}">{{$empresa->nombre}}
                                    <span class="pull-right text-red item{{$empresa->id}}"></span></a>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach

 </ul>
```

My js

```
   $(document).on('click', '.seleccion', function () {
    $('#listas').find('li').each(function () {
      console.log($(this).attr('id'))
    })
  })
```

Comment: your `li`s don't have an id

Comment: Your `li` dont have id attribute.

Comment: This is what i get in the inspector, i do get the id and all information i need 
<a href="#" id="1" data-id="1" data-nombre="Mariana" class="seleccion">Mariana
                                        <span class="pull-right text-red item1"></span></a>

Comment: @Christian yes, but they're not in the `li`, they are in the `a`. See my answer below.

Comment: I just realized that the id is in the <a>, thx for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `li`s don't actually have an `id` attribute, you should look for it in the `a` child of your `li`s, like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.seleccion', function () {
    $('#listas').find('li > a').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to read a not existing attribute from your `<li>` elements.

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->empresas as $empresa)
  <li id="myId">  <--- HERE
    <a href="#" class="seleccion" id="{{$empresa->id}}" data-id="{{$empresa->id}}"
     data-nombre="{{$empresa->nombre}}">{{$empresa->nombre}}
       <span class="pull-right text-red item{{$empresa->id}}"></span>
    </a>            
  </li>
@endforeach
```

greetings

Answer (score -1):

Like the li don't has id you must change your markup or change the js

```
  $(document).on('click', 'a.seleccion', function () {
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  });
```

Comment: Uhm... not really. They're trying to cycle on all the `li`s in the parent `ul`

Answer (score -1):

You can use **$(this)**

```
 $( ".seleccion" ).click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id'));
        console.log(id);
 });
```

Comment: Uhm... not really. They're trying to cycle on all the `li`s in the parent `ul`